# If an overdetermined system of linear equations has a solution, can it be found by ignoring some of the equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

For simplicity, take $A$ to be a $3\times 2$ matrix, and $b\in\mathbb{R}^3$. Assume the linear system of 3 equations $Ax=b$ has at least one solution. If this is the case, is it always possible to find this by deleting the last linear equation and solving the remaining 2 variable linear system?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but you'd better be absolutely sure there is a solution!

Comment: Yes, I thought so. It seems obviously true. But how would I prove it as a theorem?

Answer (score 5):

Not always. You need to make sure that the equation you're deleting is actually implied by the other equations.

Consider the system

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}x = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\17\end{pmatrix}.$$

The only solution is $x = \begin{pmatrix}0\\17\end{pmatrix}$, but if you delete the final row of $A$ and $b$ then every $x = \begin{pmatrix}0\\t\end{pmatrix}$ would be a solution.

Comment: That's a good point. How would you formulate and prove a formal result about this?

Comment: @leacorv Well, it looks like the theorem here is simply the fact that if a vector satisfies a set of equations $S$, and the equations $S$ imply another set of equations $T$, then the vector also satisfies the set of equations $S \cup T$. That's more or less just [modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
 It depends on the rank of the coefficient matrix and on the rank of the total matrix (coeff. + b), and on that of the minors obtained by subtracting one of the equations.

You can find all the explanations in any introductory lesson to Linear Algebra.